# Apply Changes to Group Policy Without Restart?

Tags: windows, group-policy

I use [LGPO tool](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/secguide/2016/01/21/lgpo-exe-local-group-policy-object-utility-v1-0/) to apply changes to GPO. But for changes to take effect, server needs to be restarted. Any possibility of applying changes without restart?

Comment: Not if the *setting* in question requires a restart, no.

Answer (score 3):

try this steps:

1. open command prompt with elevation rights (right click open as administrator)
2. `c:\>gpupdate /force`

Local Security Policy and Group Policy are different.

- Local Security Policies are local to machines and normally used for workgroup computers.
- Group Policies (GPOs) are hosted and deployed via server for larger scope management.